# Which mean value to consider for checking over indexing accounts

Tags: mean, normalization

***Problem statement:***

I am working on a project for a major game producer. The company is planning to sell the SKUs of one of their game titles (a title has multiple games) to the people who are purchasing their consoles. Let's say there are 3 games in that title - G1, G2, & G3. I have a set of accounts (players) who have engaged on their (gaming company's) consoles in the past. I want to identify the accounts that are highly likely to purchase this title's SKUs with their console purchase. Simply put, identify the specific accounts that are most likely to buy the title's SKUs along with their console purchase.

***What do I have:***

The spend on the games (of this title) by each account and the # distinct games they have played out of these three.

[image]

***My Approach:***

First, I want to take a **normalized spend value** for each account. That is, for account "A", the normalized value would be 40/2 = 20. Similarly, for others. Then, I want to take the **average** by **taking the sum of the "GAMES PLAYED" column and dividing it by the sum of the "SPEND ON THE GAME" column.** I'll then see **if the normalized value for each account (from the above example, 20 for account "A") is greater than that average value** in which case I'll assign "Y" corresponding to "A" to mark him a potential purchaser.

***The Doubt:***

This could be one way of solving this problem. Another way could be taking the average of the normalized spend value and then checking whether the normalized spend value for each account is greater than this avg. normalized spend value and mark those accounts "Y" or "N" accordingly.

Which method is more sound and whether there is a problem with any of them?Also, what would taking the average of an average mean here (average of the normalized spend value which essentially is an average value)?

*To add to it, there could be people who have neither purchased the games of this title nor spent on it and also people that have purchased the games but have not spent.*